# Mostrar / Esconder Campos usando radiobutton e jQuery

Tags: jquery, radiobutton

Como faço para que os campos venham escondidos e só apareçam com a seleção de um radio?

A baixo vou colocar os campos e a script que uso para esconder conforme clico (o que já está funcionando) o meu problema é, que quando abro o formulários, os campos estão lá e eu preciso que apareçam só quando eu selecionar algum Botão do tipo Radio

segue:

```
<script>                    
$(function(){
    $('#aprovadoSim').change(function(){
        $('#divWelcome').show();                            
        $('#divObservacoes').hide();                                                    
        $('#divRetornoCliente').hide();                         

    });
    $('#aprovadoNao').change(function(){    
        $('#divObservacoes').show();
        $('#divWelcome').hide(); 
        $('#divRetornoCliente').hide(); 
    });

    $('#aprRetornoSim').change(function(){
        $('#divWelcome').show(); 
        $('#divObservacoes').hide();
        $('#divRetornoCliente').hide(); 
    });

    $('#aprRetornoNao').change(function(){  
        $('#divObservacoes').hide();
        $('#divWelcome').hide(); 
        $('#divRetornoCliente').show(); 
    });
});         
</script>
```

HTML

```
<fieldset id="fs_aprovacao">
    <div class="panel panel-truecpa">
        <legend></legend><br />             
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="divAprovado">                                 
                        <label for="aprovado" class="col-sm-8 control-label">Aprovado?</label>                                          
                        <div class="radio" >
                            <label> <input type="radio" name="aprovado" id="aprovadoSim" value="SIM"  >Sim </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label> <input type="radio" name="aprovado" id="aprovadoNao" value="NAO" checked> Não </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>                                          
                    </div>                                          
                </div></br>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" id="divAprRetorno">                                   
                        <label for="aprRetorno" class="col-sm-8 control-label">Aprovado?</label>                                            
                        <div class="radio" >
                            <label> <input type="radio" name="aprovadoRetorno" id="aprRetornoSim" value="SIM"  >Sim </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label> <input type="radio" name="aprovadoRetorno" id="aprRetornoNao" value="NAO" > Não </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>                                          
                    </div>                                          
                </div></br>

                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="divWelcome">
                        <label for="nofiticaAdmissao" class="control-label">E-mail de Confirmação:</label>
                        <select  class="form-control" id="nofiticaAdmissao" name="nofiticaAdmissao" dataset="colleague" datasetkey="colleaguePK.colleagueId" datasetvalue="colleagueName"></select>                                                                     
                        <input type="hidden" id="colleagueId" name="colleagueId" />
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;" id="divObservacoes">
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="definicaoCliente" >
                        <label for="observacoes" class="control-label">Observações:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="observacoes" id="observacoes" rows="4" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div><br/> 
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto;" id="divRetornoCliente">
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="definicaoCliente" >
                        <label for="retornoCliente" class="control-label">Observações:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="retornoCliente" id="retornoCliente" rows="4" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div><br/>                                             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Você já tentou colocar em `divWelcome` `display:none;` ?

Comment: Sim, Mas não funcionou!

Comment: eles somem, mas quando clico nas opções que deveriam aparecer os campos, eles não aparecem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque na linha abaixo de: `$(function(){` isso:

```
$('#divWelcome, #divObservacoes, #divRetornoCliente').hide();
```

Comment: Perfeito. obrigada!!!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se seria a melhor forma de fazer isso mas desta forma funciona...

```
$('#checksim').click(function(){

  $('#input').removeAttr('type');
  $('#input').attr("type", "text")
})

$('#checknao').click(function(){

  $('#input').removeAttr('type');
  $('#input').attr("type","hidden")
})
```